# PHP PDO Dynamic query builder class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm writing a class to generate dynamic SQL insert query. I've created a test table    that has seven columns if I consider also the id that is an auto increment value otherwise the values are only six. I've tried to test if the insert function I've write works, but the console log me an error that is regarding the numbers of bounded variables: `PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.
Usually I use to write my query and this is the first time that I get this error. Is it possible that I need to include also the id column field in the query?
Here is the code:

Test page

```
<?php
$dataManager = new DataManager($db);

$table = 'hats_info';
$data = array('test0','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5');
$columns = array('materialA','materialB','materialC','materialD','accessories','hat_image');
$holders = array('?','?','?','?','?','?');

echo $dataManager->insert($data, $table, $columns, $holders);

?>
```

Class method code

```
<?php 

public function insert($table, array $data, array $columns , array $holders){

    $columns = implode(', ', array_values($columns));
    $holders = implode(', ', array_values($holders));
    $values = implode(', ', array_values($data));

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($holders)");
    return $stmt->execute(array($values));
}

?>
```

Comment: No need to implode the `data`-array though... You just could do `return $stmt->execute($data);`

Comment: Ok, but what about the comma `,` that usually separe the data in the `execute()` statement, isn't needed?

Comment: Here is a free advice: don't do this. Instead you should write custom [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) which internally used PDO directly

Comment: @tereško why?Security issues? I want to do this to avoid to write every time sql queries for my projects

Comment: Architectural issues, mostly. You are making a complexity sinkhole. There also **might be** security issues, but those would usually be avoidable ... by adding more complexity.

Comment: See the examples in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1069). You just pass all arguments as an array

Comment: Why pass array of `?`? You know size of data and can generate placeholders in a function at least.

Comment: As an aside - I don't like dynamic SQL builders; various DB vendors use different extensions to the ANSI standard. I prefer to be able to *tweak* the SQL on a vendor specific instance where required.

Comment: @tereško ok, if there aren't security issues, I will consider your tip about. If you can link some related articles that talks about this argument I will appreciate it. @DarkBee I know about, I just made this mistake because as I wrote usually I write my own query from scratch so usually I need to add the comma in the `execute()` method.

Comment: @u_mulder can you show an example?Do you talk about using a for or a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done functions like this in the following way:

```
$table = 'hats_info';

$data = [
  'materialA' => 'test0',
  'materialB' => 'test1',
  'materialC' => 'test2',
  'materialD' => 'test3',
  'accessories' => 'test4',
  'hat_image' => 'test5'
];

echo $dataManager->insert($table, $data);

public function insert($table, array $data) {
    $columns_delimited = implode(', ' array_map(
        function ($column) { return "`$column`"; },
        array_keys($data)
    ));
    $placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(1, count($data), '?'));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($columns_delimited) VALUES ($placeholders)"
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give a try to your code!